# char** memory allocation using new operator

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, char, allocation

I'm truely baffled by this throwing an error....

```
    char** results = new char*[numRes];  //this is where it breaks
    for(int i = 0; i < numRes; i++)  
    {  
         results[i] = new char[64];  
    }
```

It's throwing a corruption of the heap error. but surely it should work? Im assigning 4 char* to a list of character pointers so I can pass them into functions etc.

I looked around everywhere but they all seem to be showing the malloc and free... Im using them in classes so I want to stick to c++ new and delete.

Could someone lend me a hand please?

Comment: How do you do that assignment? `results[0]=&char1;` or something completely different?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) results[i] = new char[256];

Comment: Would you add a snippet of the code where the strings are being written to?

Comment: This is just a smiple memory allocation in the main()... it shouldnt really matter what Im going to do to it if I cant even get it to create the array of points in the first place?
but i intend to used strcpy(results[n],somestring)

Comment: @Nick Cullen: I am having the same problem. Were you able to get the solution for this problem?

Comment: @Programmer I made this post in 2012 back when I was a newcomer to programming. There is nothing in the code I originally shared that appears wrong to me.

What I would assume had happened here was I had corrupt the memory earlier on in my program and when it came to allocate memory here it would crash. I would lean towards this scenario, even more so with the line that I stated it crashed on.

Comment: Thanks for the update

Answer (score 2):

What are you doing after you allocate?  You only allocated an array of character pointers, you did not allocate space for each element (a pointer).  If you try to store items in the elements, you'll run into problems.

For example, if you wanted to store anything in results[0] after your allocation, you would need to allocate to it as well.  For example:

```
results[0] = new char[100]; // NEED TO ALLOCATE BEFORE WRITING TO results[0]!
strcpy(results[0], "Test");
```

You cannot just copy to results[0] without the allocation.  The same holds for any element of results.

Comment: I'm passing the array of char points into a method (im creating a Lua class) and I simply pass in the array of char pointers to this method -
void LUA::getResults(char** data)  //getting strings
{
 for(int i = 0; i < numOfResults; i++)
 {
  switch(queryStack())
  {
  case LUA_TSTRING:
   strcpy(data[i],readString());
   pop(); //pop the string
   break;
  case LUA_TNIL:
   break;
  default:
   printf("Unknown element debugging stack \n");
   debugStack();
   break;
  }

  pop();
 }
}

Comment: But he sayed, that he assigns char-pointers to the results-array.

Comment: Then we need to see the code to ensure it happens.  To OP, please update your post with the code snippet that shows this.

Comment: @Nick It would be 0.001% more helpful if you would unobscure that code.

Comment: So with that code snippet you just put in your comment, this answer is correct: First you need to allocate taht things where your pointer-array points to before you do `strcpy(data[i],readString());`

Comment: @pbhd Im sorry Im new to this forum Im not sure why my post came out like that, it was fine when I copied it in

Comment: I've got it written down letter for letter as you guys have said. but it still wont work. is it possible to this dynamically? because thats the way I am doing it... on the heap.

<code>
char** results = new char*[numRes];  
 for(int i = 0; i < numRes; i++)  
 {  
  results[i] = new char[64];  
 }  
<\code>

Comment: Would you modify your question to include these code changes?  It will be a lot easier to help if we can see everything together, and people can miss updates that are done in comments like this.

Comment: @user1161318 Yes sure, how do I do that?

Comment: Go to the top to your question and click on "edit", then modify your post accordingly.

Comment: Nevermind I found out the problem.... Because I am creating a lua class the functions that lua calls (from a .lua file) must be a c function and NOT a c++ function therefor using new and delete does not work in these functions i had to go with malloc and free.... it was corrupting the heap using new and delete.

Thanks alot for the help any way guys!

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating memory for a pointers array. After that you have to allocate memory for every pointer in your array. I think your code should be like this:

```
    int numRes = 4;
    char** results = new char*[numRes];

    for(int i=0; i<numRes; i++)
    {
         results[i] = new char;
    }
```

Comment: It cant be as the program is breaking at the line "   char** results = new char*[numRes];"
Btw - im new to this forum so Im not sure how to post nicely formatted replies :(

Comment: If it really breaks at that allocation, then your heap is allready corrupt, and you need to search what happened before. Nevertheless, you have another error in your code which is covered by the other answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

If using c++ is it possible to use STL?  specifically std::string, and std::list or std::vector classes in your code?  Unlike traditional c-strings, which are mere sequences of characters in a memory array, C++ string objects belong to a class with many built-in features to operate with strings in a more intuitive way and with some additional useful features common to C++ containers.

```
#include <string>
#include <list>

std::list<std::string> results; // create a list of strings

// and populate it
results.push_back("blah");
results.push_back("blah1");
results.push_back("blah2");
...
```